# Tables with math, equal column width, and right alignment

Tags: tables

Q: Is there an approach, less hacky than my `\MyLen` approach, that would generate roughly the second table below? I'd like to maintain professional features (but I welcome criticisms wholeheartedly!) like (1) `booktabs` effects, (2) right alignment of data, (3) no vertical rules, (4) horizontal rule only to separate estimators and column titles, (5) equal column widths, (6) and tight spacing of columns.

I generated the following table and thought it didn't look terribly professional because of the different column widths (Q: Am I wrong? Should this table be left alone?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrr@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & $-$1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & $-$1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & $-$4.35 & $-$12.91 & $-$26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & $-$2.03 & $-$2.52 & $-$1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & $-$1.87 & $-$2.26 & $-$1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & $-$0.24 & 4.25    & 12.93   & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{my caption}
\end{table}
```

[image: tab1]

```
\newlength{\MyLen}
\settowidth{\MyLen}{$-$26.35}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\the\MyLen}}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & $-$1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & $-$1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & $-$4.35 & $-$12.91 & $-$26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & $-$2.03 & $-$2.52 & $-$1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & $-$1.87 & $-$2.26 & $-$1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & $-$0.24 & 4.25    & 12.93   & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{my caption}
\end{table}
```

[image: tab2]

I like this table. More professional (But again, any comments? On second look, the columns do look a little wide). Although, I don't like having to use the `\MyLen` hack. I thought there might be a less hacky approach using the `tabularx` package:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & $-$1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & $-$1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & $-$4.35 & $-$12.91 & $-$26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & $-$2.03 & $-$2.52 & $-$1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & $-$1.87 & $-$2.26 & $-$1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & $-$0.24 & 4.25    & 12.93   & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{my caption}
\end{table}
```

[image: tab3]

I like that the columns are tighter but there is some weird stuff going on with that 3rd data row (Q: Any clue what's going on there?)

Comment: I wouldn't say your length approach is a hack. The alternative (defining some environment that automatically identifies the largest item in all the columns) is doable, but would have to do a lot of leg-work in the background. You'd have to read in the entire table and parse the column entries, and then (re)typeset the entire table. For example, the [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty) does this (I think) to maintain a balanced look. Foregoing this, `\MyLen` is the easy (and convenient) way out if you know your table entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really dislike how you are doing the minus signs. Since all your data is two digits a simpler solution in this case for the last table would be to use

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{math}}r<{\end{math}}}
```

and eliminate the `$-$` hack.  Also, you could consider centering the titles: MPE and MAPE.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use the `S` column type from [the `siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) to align on the decimal point. This also ends up shifting the "Jumps" row so if that is not desired you could manually adjust that row:

[image]

### Note:

- I am not sure why, but using the `S` column type necessitated replacing the `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` with `\cmidrule{1-9}`.

---

### Code: Modified `R` Column Type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{math}}r<{\end{math}}}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                &  2.14 &  2.42 &   1.35 & -1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  &  1.99 &  2.16 &   1.12 & -1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ &  0.35 & -4.35 & -12.91 & -26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & -2.03 & -2.52 &  -1.33 &   1.73 & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & -1.87 & -2.26 &  -1.10 &   1.87 & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & -0.24 &  4.25 &  12.93 &  26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{my caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `siunitx` version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lSSSSSSSS@{}}
 %\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lrrrrrrrr@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \cmidrule{1-9}
    $\widetilde{JV}$                &  2.14 &  2.42 &   1.35 & -1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  &  1.99 &  2.16 &   1.12 & -1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ &  0.35 & -4.35 & -12.91 & -26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
    \cmidrule{1-9}
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & -2.03 & -2.52 &  -1.33 &   1.73 & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & -1.87 & -2.26 &  -1.10 &   1.87 & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & -0.24 &  4.25 &  12.93 &  26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \cmidrule{1-9}
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{my caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I used the `xtable` package in R to automatically output this table. It gives the funny `$-$` hack, which is nice in a way because I can just use the regular `r` columns rather than specifying a `\newcolumntype`. But I think I'm going to use your approach now. Also, your solution is a good one to replace the first table where the column widths are not uniform. But it doesn't really work as a replacement for the 3rd table since it doesn't use equal column widths or the `X` columntype from `tabularx`

Comment: Have updated to include an alternate solution using the `siunitx` package that provides the `S` column type to align on the decimal point.