# Options for decreasing this table's width?

Tags: tables

I like the style of the following table (booktabs effects, nice caption, equal width of data columns, right alignment of data, width set equal to the `\linewidth`, able to look at two estimator evaluation criteria side-by-side (MPE and MAPE), etc.). What I do NOT like is the imperfect right-alignment of the data (e.g., see data row 3) because there's a little too much "stuff" in the table and `tabularx` is trying to get all of it to fit within `\linewidth`.

Q: What are some good/standard options for dealing with this problem of a table with content that is too wide for the document?

I figure a few are:

1. Use `longtable` and display the table in landscape (Would rather not do this. But it's not the worst approach)
2. Stack the table so that the "Est." column is repeated once and "MPE" section is above the "MAPE" section (Would rather not do this. Like the idea of being able to look straight across the table)
3. Decrease the font size of the document or the table (Not really an option. I just don't like this approach)
4. Don't insist on equal column-widths so that columns without "-" signs are a little smaller. Then everything can fit (Really don't like this approach. Prefer equal column widths)
5. Decrease `\tabcolsep`. (Not bad)
6. Remove a digit. (This is probably my leading candidate)

[image: tab1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,figureposition=top]{caption}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}X<{$}}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & -1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & -1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & -4.35   & -12.91   & -26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & -2.03 & -2.52 & -1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & -1.87 & -2.26 & -1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & -0.24 & 4.25  & 12.93 & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

NOTE: This is an extension of [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41861/tables-with-math-equal-column-width-and-right-alignment) of mine where I was just trying to figure out how to do equal column widths and right-alignment in a table.

Comment: You could simply transpose the table, but keeping MPE and MAPE at the top, although that does not always make sense, data wise. Else I would try to do without the `\diagbox`, or if you really like it, remove space in that box so that it typesets smaller.

Comment: @zeroth: +1 for the transpose and +1 for removing the `\diagbox`, I find such things disguisting

Comment: @tohecz: I'm curious why you find the `\diagbox` disgusting? What would you propose instead? Eliminating "Est." or "Jumps"? Adding an extra row to label "Est." and "Jumps" separately?

Comment: @brianjd I will have to agree, it seems unstructered to the eye. However, some do like them as they can be very descriptive, in your case `Est.` is likely not descriptive, whence it could be left out. In that case you could right align _Jumps_ or do _Jumps:_ to show its relation to the row. Or further you could add _Jumps_ after MPE and MAPE as those do seem to be related.

Comment: @brianjd: I can't say I have a specific reason, just a feeling in my eye. The diagonal line simply visually breaks the structure of the table. **First suggestion:** I would probably remove the word `Est.` completely and think out a good caption of the table. Everybody who reads your article know what those `JV` and `IV` mean, and who did not, `Est.` abbreviation wouldn't help him anyways. **Second suggestion:** If you make `Jumps` and `0,3,10,30` in bold, you visually connect them and therefore it is clear, "who is who".

Comment: not sure whether this works for tabularx, but for regular `tabular` a quick and dirty work around might be to reduce the space between columns slightly, e.g. `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}`

Comment: @tohecz: These are great suggestions. I'm trying them out. Thinking now that I need to switch the "jumps" and "MPE/MAPE" rows. Doesn't make sense to have "MPE" right above "0,3,10,30"...those are jumps! If I do switch the rows and take your advice, things look a bit better. I never would've thought designing a table would be this complicated!

Comment: @brianjd: I found out that for most of the things, you have good defaults considering the graphical output, but not for tables. They are always a nut-case!

Answer (score 2):

I'd take less space for the first column and use `dcolumn` rather than `tabularx` which ensures the numbers align and makes latex work a lot less hard, note this uses 2.2 as the size specifier which means no space is allocated for the minus signs and they stick into the intercolumn space, but I think that's OK here (and you haven't room for a specification of 3.2)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,figureposition=top]{caption}
\begin{document}
%\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}X<{$}}
\newcolumntype{R}{D{.}{.}{2.2}}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \small\diagbox[trim=lr,width=4.5em]{Est.}{\kern3ptJumps\kern-3pt}& 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & -1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & -1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & -4.35   & -12.91   & -26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & -2.03 & -2.52 & -1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & -1.87 & -2.26 & -1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & -0.24 & 4.25  & 12.93 & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (I do not know whether it is a good way or not, but should do since you have given me only limited options) is to use `fullpage`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage} %<======================== here.
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,figureposition=top]{caption}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}X<{$}}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
  \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}lRRRRRRRR@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MPE} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MAPE}\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}  \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    \diagbox[trim=lr]{Est.}{Jumps} & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 & 0 & 3 & 10 & 30 \\
    \midrule
    $\widetilde{JV}$                & 2.14 & 2.42    & 1.35     & -1.69  & 2.14 & 4.57 & 4.92  & 4.74 \\
    $\widehat{JV}$                  & 1.99 & 2.16    & 1.12     & -1.83  & 1.99 & 4.47 & 4.91  & 4.81 \\
    $\widehat{JV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & 0.35 & -4.35   & -12.91   & -26.35 & 3.11 & 5.48 & 12.95 & 26.35 \\
     \midrule
    $\widetilde{IV}$                & -2.03 & -2.52 & -1.33 & 1.73  & 6.54 & 6.37 & 5.24  & 3.71 \\
    $\widehat{IV}$                  & -1.87 & -2.26 & -1.10 & 1.87  & 6.48 & 6.31 & 5.23  & 3.80 \\
    $\widehat{IV}_{\mathrm{BNS04}}$ & -0.24 & 4.25  & 12.93 & 26.39 & 6.61 & 7.06 & 13.11 & 26.39 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
%==================================
\end{document}
```

[image]