# How to create multicolumn with a diagonal line

Tags: tables

How to join two columns in a table row and add diagonal line like this:

```
+-----+--+--+--+
| \ k |  |  |  |
|  \  |  |  |  |
|   \ |  |  |  |
| M  \|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Comment: Use the [diagbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/diagbox) package.

Comment: Could you please check if [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell) answers your question?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I cannot use diagbox package since it's not a default package :(

Comment: Yes it is (in TeX Live, at least).

Comment: @kan, this trick doesn't work for a multicolumn, therefore I created a separate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to diagonally divide a table cell … properly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89745/5764)

Comment: ...for some more examples on the use of [`diagbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox), see [Tables with math, equal column width, and right alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41861/5764).

Comment: @Werner, I have a problem with joined columns like in my example, so it is not a duplicate of "How to diagonally divide a table cell … properly". And I cannot use diagbox because it is not a default package and this fact can lead to problems in a Journal where I'm going to publish my article.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _default package_? The ones in `tex/latex/base/`?

Comment: @cgnieder, I mean that you need to install additional files to make it works. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Warlock diagbox is part of either two major TeX distributions, MiKTeX 2.9 and TeX Live 2012. If you have one one them you shouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: @cgnieder, I have TeX Live, but diagbox doesn't work. I will test it today again and I will provide results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to answer for my own question. The solution, that created on the base of [diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell) is

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{2}{|p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep},minimum height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight] (box) {};
  \draw (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \caption{bla bla bla}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline 
        \diag{.1em}{2.5em}{ $M$ }{ $k$ }  & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 9 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{9}} & $ \xi_k $ & -0.9682 & -0.8360 & -0.6134 & -0.3243 & 0.0000 & 0.3243 & 0.6134 & 0.8360 & 0.9682 \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-11}    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & $ \gamma_k $ & 0.0813 & 0.1806 & 0.2606 & 0.3123 & 0.3302 & 0.3123 & 0.2606 & 0.1806 & 0.0813 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
```